# OleDb Excel Connection Error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException"

Tags: vb.net, excel, database-connection, oledb, oledbconnection

I've created a small vb.net application that connects to a an excel sheet on a shared folder.
It works great if i open the excel before using the the application , the issue is when the excel isn't open in the background i get a "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" error when trying to open a connection.

I've read a bit about this error and i understand it has something to do with access rights to a local temp library.
So my questions are:
1) Is there a solution?
2) Is this the best connection strategy for my situation where the excel files sit on a shared drive?

Connection code:

```
    skuPath = "C:\path.xlsm"
    cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + skuPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    q1 = "select * from [" + year + "$B4:V128]"
    da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(q1, cn)
    cn.Open()
    da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    cn.Close()
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
```

I receive the error on cn.Open().

Comment: What is the exact error message? If the error is on the Open line you have a problem with your connection string or with the underlying OleDbProvider. The exact problem is stated in the rest of the error message

Comment: Also, trying to open a file in the root folder of the disk is always a problem. Do you have the required permissions to read/write there?

Comment: And I could be wrong, but XLSM is for _Excel Open XML Macro-Enabled Spreadsheet_ that is a post Office 2003 feature, thus requires ACE.OleDB.12.0 as OleDb provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got exactly the same problem few weeks ago. 
Error is caused by incorrect version of oledb provider, just as Steve suggested. 
 
Try this:

```
skuPath = "C:\path.xlsm"
cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "data source=" + skuPath + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes""")
q1 = "select * from [" + year + "$B4:V128]"
da = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(q1, cn)
cn.Open()
da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
cn.Close()
dt = ds.Tables(0)
```